# What does 日本語で送っても読めますか？ mean?

Tags: translation

I mean I understand all the parts separately but I can't lay my finger on the core meaning of the sentence.

Whole message:

> Hi I'm maho !
>   17years old, from Japan.
>   your Japanese is good !
>   my English is poor.
>   
>   日本語で送っても読めますか？
>   
>   I want to be your pen pal.
>   
>   Good bye

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 日本語で送っても読めますか?

istrasci’s first translation is good:

> (Even) If I send the (mail) in Japanese, will you be able to read it?

(It is a little silly to ask this question in Japanese, because if the answer is “no,” you are not expected to understand the question….)

The で in the sentence is a [case marker which signifies place, time, means, cause, and so on](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E3%81%A7&dtype=0&dname=0ss&stype=1&pagenum=1&index=113244500000), and in this case, it signifies means.

istrasci raised an interesting point: 日本語で (in Japanese) does not state a means of sending a mail.  Means of sending a mail include “by air mail,” “by sea mail,” “electronically,” and so on, but “in Japanese” is a means of *composing* a mail, not a means of *sending* a composed mail.

However, (手紙を/メールを)送る does not always refer to the mere action of sending an already composed mail.  It can collectively refer to the action of composing and sending a mail.  In this sense, 日本語で indeed describes a means of this broader action.

As an aside, I note that case marker で etymologically arises from copula.  Slightly more precisely, case marker で originates from にて and copula だ originates from にてあり, and these にて are the same thing (the combination of case marker に and particle て).  But we usually distinguish case marker で from copula when we talk about the Japanese grammar.  As dainichi wrote, *this で is no more a connective form of copula than all で particles are*.

Answer (score 0):

> "(Even) If I send the (mail) in Japanese, will you be able to read it?"

Note that although "in Japanese" (`日本語で`) is not a *method* of sending something (such as air-mail, ground-mail, carrier-pigeon, etc. are), @TsuyoshiIto points out that it's (become?) acceptable for `送る` in this case to mean not just the sending of the mail, but the entire process of composing **and** sending the mail (a "shorthand" for `メールを書いて送る`).  In reference to this entire process, then `日本語で` can be used to describe the means of this broader action.

Comment: @user1205935:  How do you send something "in" Japanese?  Japanese is not a method of conveyance.  Like if I go to send a package, my choices might include "3 day ground", or "next day air", but I'm certain "Japanese" will not be on there.  You send mail that is *written* in Japanese.

Comment: "Sending a letter in Japanese" [sic] sounds like good English to me. Similarly, "I will reply to you _in_ English". My point was that, in my opinion, で is not limited to "methods of conveyance" as you call it.

Comment: @user1205935:  Yes, "Sending a letter in Japanese" is correct English, but the `in Japanese` refers to the state of the letter, not the action of how you sent it.  However, the `で` you are talking about describes the means of how you do the action.  You say `航空便で送る` or `船便で送る`; `日本語で送る` doesn't make sense.  If you want to describe the letter being in Japanese, Maho should have said `日本語で書いて送っても読めますか？`

Comment: You have the point that technically, we do not send it in some language, but we write it in some language and send it.  Similarly, technically, 日本語で送る does not describe the means of sending a letter.  Yet, we sometimes consider writing a letter as part of the action of sending a letter and say 日本語で送る to mean what would be 日本語で書いて送る if we made a distinction between the actions of writing and sending, and this で is still the case particle which describes means.

Comment: We say「日本語でメールを送る」, so I thought 「メールを」was left out before the「日本語で送っても読めますか？」... Btw, does "to email in Japanese"(←日本語でメールする) sound awkward?

Comment: So wait, is the で in 日本語でメールを送る also not particle で..!?

Comment: This で is no more a connective form of copula than all で particles are. Sure, in "Sending a letter in Japanese" you can consider "in Japanese" part of the NP "a letter in Japanese", but how about "Can I send it in Japanese"? You won't convince anyone that "it in Japanese" is a NP.

Comment: So 日本語で送る is a copula while something like 日本語でメールを書いて送る would be particle で, desho?

Comment: @ssb: No, で is a particle in both sentences.

Comment: In this context 日本語 in 日本語で could mean the specific encoding method that the sender used. If so, the expression 日本語で送る completely makes sense as well as "send it in Unicode" and it definitely should be just 日本語で送る, not 日本語で書いて送る.