# 「日本語で、送って」What are the contexts of this usage of "send"?

Tags: word-choice

I recently posted on Facebook lyrics to a Simon & Garfunkel song. A friend then posted:

> ニック…日本語で、送って

I know 送る means to send, but does she want me to 'send' the lyrics to her in Japanese or is she asking me to send her a video with a Japanese translation? Or maybe something different altogether?

Comment: See lengthy discussion [HERE](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11283/78) for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question doesn't really give detailed context to the situation and her sentence is ambiguous in general,  but I can surmise that she means she wants you to send her the lyrics in Japanese. It's possible that she doesn't know they are lyrics and just wants to know what you are writing in English, or it's possible that she wants a translation. So in this context, 送って would mean to "give" a translation. You can think of it akin to "sending" e-mail which is why in Japanese they would use that word for electronic communication.